# Update and remove Vector values based on a condition in RUST

Tags: vector, rust

I there. This is my vector: will help you to understand my problem better.

```
let mut entries = vec![("Batman",1000),
                       ("SuperMan",500),
                       ("Wonder-women",100),
                       ("Batman",2000)
                      ]
```

One superhero's name and the other is the money he/she added to an account.

1)I want to get Batman entries

2)Let say I want to minus 2500 from Batman's account. So the latest entry of ("Batman",2000) will be removed, and the remaining 500 would be removed from his other entry.

3)if money equals zero remove that entry.

Final Result:

```
let mut entries = vec![("Batman",500),
                       ("SuperMan",500),
                       ("Wonder-women",100),
                      ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good fit for a `Vec`, have you considered using a `HashMap`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth there is one more value which I didn't added

Comment: Something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67a9b43a4373b207b1b4c9be959d6d46)?